How Can I Simulate Weak or Intermittent Network Connections in Android Studio for Testing?
I’m currently developing an Android app, and I want to test how it performs under weak or intermittent network conditions. For example, I’d like to simulate scenarios like:

Slow network speeds (e.g., 2G or poor Wi-Fi).

Frequent connection drops or high packet loss.

Switching between Wi-Fi and mobile data.


I’ve heard about the Network Profiler in Android Studio, but it seems more for monitoring rather than simulating these issues.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Using the Android Emulator Extended Controls to set different network speeds (e.g., GSM, EDGE), but it doesn’t allow for intermittent drops or advanced customization.

Looking into third-party tools like Charles Proxy or Fiddler, but they seem more focused on inspecting network traffic.


Does anyone know a good way to simulate these network conditions? Ideally, I’d like a solution that integrates well with Android Studio or the Emulator, but I’m open to other approaches as long as they’re beginner-friendly.
Any tips or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Send your network traffic through a proxy, similar to Charles Proxy, which can emulate different network conditions.  Just set up the proxy settings for the device/emulator.  They absolutely can be used to set up deteriorating network conditions.
